# Is PlantUML capable of representing finite state machine diagrams with parallel states?

Tags: state-machine, plantuml

I have a finite state machine diagram which I'd like to document with PlantUML, but the state machine diagram employs [parallel states](https://statecharts.dev/state-machine-state-explosion.html) to represent how multiple event sources evolve independently except in very particular cases.  Does PlantUML provide a way to represent parallel states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://plantuml.com/state-diagram) show concurrent states exist.

```
@startuml
[*] --> Active

state Active {
  [*] -> NumLockOff
  NumLockOff --> NumLockOn : EvNumLockPressed
  NumLockOn --> NumLockOff : EvNumLockPressed
  --
  [*] -> CapsLockOff
  CapsLockOff --> CapsLockOn : EvCapsLockPressed
  CapsLockOn --> CapsLockOff : EvCapsLockPressed
  --
  [*] -> ScrollLockOff
  ScrollLockOff --> ScrollLockOn : EvCapsLockPressed
  ScrollLockOn --> ScrollLockOff : EvCapsLockPressed
}

@enduml
```

[image: concurrent states]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough example.  However, it seems that PlantUML does not support including the same substates in more than one state.  For example.  I tried to add a `IsOnline`/`IsOffline` state to an `Active` and `Inactive` states and PlantUML flagged that as an error.

Comment: @RAM can you put your link to the sample that has the error here, on http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ ?

Comment: @RAM it makes sense to me that you can't have the same state in two composite states. Maybe post your question as a separate question with the example and what you're trying to do.